# Как округлить края у QPixmap PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qpixmap, qpainterpath

Пытаюсь округлить края у изображения, вставленного в `QPixmap`.

У `QLabel` это спокойно осуществляется с помощью `border-radius: Npx`, а здесь такое не прокатывает.

Не подскажете, как я могу округлить изображение в `QPixmap`?

P.S. Нужный `QPixmap` я обозначил комментарием в коде.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys
import mutagen

DEFAULT_STYLE = """
QProgressBar{
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 10px;
   
}
"""
sliderSheet = """

QSlider::handle {
    height: 10px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0 -4px; 
}

QSlider::add-page {
    background: transparent;
}

QSlider::sub-page {
    background: yellow;
}

"""

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("images/mp3-player.ico"))
        self.setWindowTitle("MP3-Player")
        self.setFixedSize(700,700)

        self.first_open_pixmap = QPixmap("images/start_picture.png")
        self.background_pixmap = QPixmap("images/background.jpg")

        self.background_pixmap = self.background_pixmap.scaled(1200,1200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)

        self.background_label = QLabel(self)
        self.background_label.hide()
        self.background_label.setPixmap(self.background_pixmap)

        self.first_open_label = QLabel(self)
        self.first_open_label.setPixmap(self.first_open_pixmap)

        self.central_label = QLabel(self)
        self.central_label.setGeometry(100,50,500,500)
        self.central_label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(147,147,147); border-radius: 25px")
        self.central_label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.central_label.hide()

        self.slider = QSlider(self)
        self.slider.hide()

        self.start_progress_bar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.start_progress_bar.setGeometry(150,400,350,10)
        self.start_progress_bar.setStyleSheet(DEFAULT_STYLE)

        self.start_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.start_button.setIcon(QIcon('images/start.png'))
        self.start_button.setIconSize(QSize(70, 70))
        self.start_button.hide()

        self.next_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.next_button.setIcon(QIcon('images/next.png'))
        self.next_button.setIconSize(QSize(90, 90))
        self.next_button.hide()

        self.previous_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.previous_button.setIcon(QIcon('images/previous.png'))
        self.previous_button.setIconSize(QSize(60, 60))
        self.previous_button.hide()

        self.package = QFileDialog(self)
        self.package_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.package_button.setIcon(QIcon('images/package.png'))
        self.package_button.setIconSize(QSize(60, 60))
        self.package_button.hide()

        self.time = 0
        self.new_view = False
        self.music_here = False
        self.start_stop = 0
        self.value = 0

        self.timer_duration = QTimer(self)
        self.start_timer = QTimer(self)

        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.play_music)
        self.start_timer.timeout.connect(self.first_open_app)
        self.package_button.clicked.connect(self.open_package)
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next_secs)
        self.previous_button.clicked.connect(self.prev_secs)
        self.timer_duration.timeout.connect(self.value_slider)

        self.first_open_app()

    def first_open_app(self):
        self.time+=1
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94)")

        self.first_open_label.setGeometry(250,200,200,150)

        self.start_timer.start(5)

        self.start_progress_bar.setValue(self.time)
        self.start_progress_bar.setFormat("")

        if self.time == 100:
            self.start_timer.stop()
            self.prepare_main_app()

    def prepare_main_app(self):
        self.first_open_label.hide()
        self.start_progress_bar.hide()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255)")
        self.new_view = True

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.new_view == True:

            self.start_progress_bar.setGeometry(150 ,380 , 375,15 )
            self.central_label.show()

            self.start_button.show()
            self.start_button.setGeometry(160,635 , 60,60)
            self.start_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(147,147,147); \
                                             border-radius: 15px")

            self.next_button.show()
            self.next_button.setGeometry(90, 635 , 60, 60)
            self.next_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(147,147,147); \
                                           border-radius: 15px")
            self.previous_button.show()
            self.previous_button.setGeometry(230, 635 , 60, 60)
            self.previous_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(147,147,147); \
                                                border-radius: 15px")

            self.package_button.show()
            self.package_button.setGeometry(300, 635, 60, 60)
            self.package_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97); \
                                               border-radius: 20px;")

            self.slider.show()
            self.slider.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
            self.slider.setGeometry(100,620, 500,5)
            self.slider.setStyleSheet(sliderSheet)

            self.background_label.show()
            self.background_label.setGeometry(0,0,700,700)

    def play_music(self):
        if self.music_here == True:
                self.start_stop+=1

                if self.start_stop%2 == 0:
                    self.start_button.setIcon(QIcon('images/start.png'))
                    self.start_button.setIconSize(QSize(70, 70))

                    self.player.pause()
                    self.timer_duration.stop()

                if self.start_stop%2 == 1:
                    self.start_button.setIcon(QIcon('images/stop.png'))
                    self.start_button.setIconSize(QSize(70, 70))

                    self.player.play()
                    self.timer_duration.start(1000)

    def value_slider(self):
        self.slider.setRange(0, self.player.duration()//1000)
        self.current_value = self.slider.value()

        self.value+=1

        self.slider.setValue(self.value)

        if self.slider.value() >= self.player.duration()//1000:
            self.value = 0
            self.start_stop = 0

            self.slider.setValue(0)
            self.player.setPosition(0)

            self.player.stop()
            self.timer_duration.stop()

            self.start_button.setIcon(QIcon('images/start.png'))
            self.start_button.setIconSize(QSize(70, 70))

    def prev_secs(self):
        if self.slider.value() > 0:
            self.player.setPosition(self.player.position() + 10000)
            self.slider.setValue(self.slider.value() + 10)

            self.value+=10

    def next_secs(self):
        if self.slider.value() > 10:
            self.player.setPosition(self.player.position() - 10000)
            self.slider.setValue(self.slider.value() - 10)

            self.value -= 10

        if self.slider.value() <=10 and self.slider.value()> 0:
            self.player.setPosition(0)
            self.slider.setValue(0)

            self.value = 0

    def open_package(self):
        self.name = QUrl(self.package.getOpenFileUrl()[0])

        if self.name != QUrl(""):
            self.music_here = True
            self.content = QMediaContent(self.name)

            self.player = QMediaPlayer()
            self.player.setMedia(self.content)

            pixlist = self.saveMP3pix(self.name)
            self.saveMP3tags(self.name)

            try:
                pixmap = QPixmap(pixlist[0])   #<Речь идет об этой части кода
                self.central_label.setPixmap(pixmap) #

            except:
                pass

    def saveMP3pix(self, filename):
        filename = filename.toLocalFile()
        mp3 = mutagen.File(filename)

        allpix = []

        for tag in mp3.items():
            if tag[0][:4] == 'APIC':
                pic = tag[1]
                new_name = f'my_pic_{len(allpix)}.' + str(pic.mime.split('/')[1])
                file = open(new_name, "wb")

                file.write(pic.data)
                file.close()
                allpix.append(new_name)

        return allpix

    def saveMP3tags(self, filename):
        filename = filename.toLocalFile()

        for i in range(1,len(filename)+1):
            if filename[-i] == "/":
                self.name = filename[-i+1:-4]
                self.directory_name = filename[:-i+1]

                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('lena.jpg')
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        w = pixmap.size().width()
        h = pixmap.size().height()
        
        clipPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        clipPath.addRoundedRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, w, h), w//2, h//2)
            
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        qp.setClipPath(clipPath)
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, QtGui.QPixmap('lena.jpg'))
        qp.end()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        lbl.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('lena.jpg'))
        layout.addWidget(lbl, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю... Побежал пробовать)

Comment: Ой, получается не совсем так, как нужно. Осуществляется отрисовка круга, мне же нужно, чтобы QPixmap полностью принял форму QLabel. Скриншот я приложил в вопросе. Возможно ли сделать так, как я задумал или лучше смириться?

Comment: @Bitchdragon, задайте новый вопрос. Прикрепите минимально-воспроизводимый пример. который демонстрирует проблему. Прикрепите ваше изображение и хорошо объясните что не так получается в ваше примере и какой результат вы хотели получить.